# Simple For Loop Output

Tags: php

```
for ($i = $field +1;  $i < $field2; $i++) {
    echo $i.'<br/>';
}
```

what i'm trying to do here is Echo numbers between the input values field and field2, this works, however i was wondering if there was a more efficient way of doing this (eg changing the $i = $field +1;)

Comment: That's about as efficient as it gets.... changing `$i++` to `$++$i` is a micro-optimisation

Comment: An alternative might be `echo implode('<br/>', range($field+1, $field2));` instead of the loop, but it won't necessarily be faster (depending on the difference between $field and $field2; and will almost certainly use more memory, probably making it less efficient overall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another using while loop example:

```
<?php
$i = $field;
while(++$i < $field2) {
  echo $i.'<br/>';
}
```

Comment: [php benchmark](http://phpbench.com/) has a comparison of for against while. Their conclusion: `Conclusion: 
Well there you have it, the while loop 90% of the time is indeed slightly faster`